# Cannot read property 'setAllowScrolling' of undefined. React with fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullpage.js

I am trying to disable scrolling while a modal pop-up is open. The following if statement does disable scroll while the modal is open, but after the modal is closed, scrolling is still disabled

```
if (isMoreInfoOpen === true) {
    fullpageApi.setAllowScrolling(false);
}
```

To fix that issue, I added an else statement to turn scrolling back on after the modal has been closed.

```
if (isMoreInfoOpen === true) {
    fullpageApi.setAllowScrolling(false);
} else {
   fullpageApi.setAllowScrolling(true);
}
```

However, adding the else statement causes an error:
Cannot read property 'setAllowScrolling' of undefined

I've recreated the issue here: https://7pq3i.csb.app/

Comment: Have you tried using `fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling` instead?

Comment: I'm getting the same error with fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling

Comment: I assume you are using the [official react wrapper for fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage)?

If that's the case I would encourage you to take a look at [the examples](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage/tree/master/examples) and if you still have issues you can create a reproduction on this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m34yq5q0qx)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fullpagejs-example-forked-k5rkd?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Create a function for your toggle check. 
Then call it on the `afterRender` callback offered by fullPage.js. Use then `fullpage_api` there.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue while trying to disable react-fullpage scrolling when a fullpage menu was opened. This seems to have fixed it for me:

```
if (isNavOpen) {
            fullpageApi.setAllowScrolling(false)
            console.log('fp scrolling locked')
          }
else if (state.initialized === true && isNavOpen === false) {
            fullpageApi.setAllowScrolling(true)
            console.log('fp scrolling unlocked')
          }
```

Checking to see that react-fullpage state is initialized and the nav is open seems to resolve the undefined error.

I am using react-context to store my "isNavOpen" state, and 'state.initialized' refers to the react-fullpage state render props.

Comment: hmm I tried your solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fullpagejs-example-forked-k5rkd?file=/src/index.js but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
window.fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(<true/false>)
```

So for me, in `componentDidMount`, I got this to work by first checking to see if the modal is open and if so, setting

```
window.fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false)
```

In my modal component, I have a closeModal function, and there, I open this back up with

```
window.fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true)
```

This is working for me, so hope this helps you out!  I'm not sure if this is optimal, but it is working and I'll continue playing and post if I find out anything else.

Comment: Hello!

Please let me known after setAllowScrolling(false) my Navbar scroll is also not working?

Is that any solution for it

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if fullpageApi is initialized. Something like this...

```
if (fullpageApi) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up avoiding the setAllowScroll method by using normalScrollElements.

Just added the modal class name:

```
normalScrollElements = {'.modal-container'}
```

Works well on mobile but have had issues with it on desktop.